# Can a polynomial also be a vector?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

To the best of my knowledge, a vector is defined simply as a member of a particular linear space. Since we can construct a linear space composed out of polynomial expressions above the real field, I conclude that a polynomial from that vector space is a vector — because that's how we defined it.

What I struggle to understand is what happens when we start working with linear transformations. Assuming I have a linear operator $T: \mathbb{R}_n[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_n[x]$, its representing matrix will allow for $T(v) = Av$, where $A$ is the representing matrix and $v \in \mathbb{R}_n[x]$. But how do we multiply a matrix by a polynomial, **unless** we treat it like a vector?

To help clarify what I'm trying to ask: I've been told that when finding the eigenvectors of $A$ for the above transformation, I must transform the vector coordinates into the polynomial field. But, if a polynomial isn't a vector, it sounds wrong to me to do so.

Comment: That's the whole point.  It's a matrix *representation* of a linear transformation.  The original situation need not have anything to do with matrices or vectors.  Once you choose bases, the coordinates allow you to treat things like vectors up to an iso.

Comment: To clarify @Randall : "Once you choose bases, the coordinates allow you to treat things like *column* vectors", so that the evaluation of a linear function can be represented as a matrix-vector product. As OP said, vectors are elements of a vector space, the set of polynomials can be considered as one example.

Comment: @LutzL  To clarify even further, depends on whether or not you write functions as $(x)f$ or $f(x)$.

Comment: @Randall : Could you explain, what is $(x)f$? Is that meant as the evaluation operator? Then yes, it is a linear functional, but does not have values in the polynomial space. One could make a distinction of the space of polynomials as coefficient sequences and the space of polynomial functions as subset of the space of continuous functions.

Comment: Some people--depending on geography--write function arguments on the left, not the right.  For them, you must use row vectors to make the matrix-vector product work out correctly.

Comment: the set of all polynomials with degree lower than a fixed $n$ is a vector space with the common operations between polynomials.
Your basis is the set $\{1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^n\}$ and any linear transformation $T$ is defined by the images of $T(x^k)$, so its matrix will contain polinomials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say $T(v)=Av$. This is wrong. You should say $$[T(v)]_{B'}=A[v]_{B}$$

where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$ of the domain and the basis $B'$ of the co-domain. Here $[T(v)]_{B'}$ is the coordinate vector with respect to $B'$ and $[v]_{B}$ is the coordinate vector with respect to $B$.

So instead of multiplying the matrix with a polynomial, the effect of the linear transformation is captured by multiplying the matrix with the coordinate vector (i.e. the column matrix) of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a matrix to do that. If, say, $T(P)(x)=P(x+1)$, then $T$ is linear, but you can compute $T(P)$ for any polynomial without using a matrix. You *may* use a matrix, but it is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

You have put your attention on a very interesting subject, that here can be only summarily surveyed.

Well, if we define the vector
$$
{\bf x}_{\,h} (x) = \left( {\matrix{
   {x^{\,0} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,1} }  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {x^{\,h} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
then any polynomial, of degree not greater than $h$, can be expressed as:
$$
p_{\,h} (x) = {\bf a}_{\,h}  \cdot {\bf x}_{\,h} (x) = \overline {{\bf a}_{\,h} } \,{\bf x}_{\,h} (x)
$$
thereby establishing, in base ${\bf x}_{\,h}$, an isomorphism between the polynomials and the coefficient vectors ${\bf a}_{\,h}$.

This correspondence is useful in many sectors of polynomial analysis.

One is the change of basis. For instance if we take as basis the [Rising Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) of $x$
$$
{\bf y}_{\,h} (x) = \left( {\matrix{
   {x^{\,\overline {\,0\,} }  = 1}  \cr 
   {x^{\,\overline {\,1\,} }  = x}  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {x^{\,\overline {\,h\,} }  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{h - 1} {\left( {x + k} \right)} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
then we know that the relation between the bases is given by the Stirling N. of 1st kind
$$
{\bf y}_{\,h} (x) = \left( {\matrix{
   {x^{\,\overline {\,0\,} } }  \cr 
   {x^{\,\overline {\,1\,} } }  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {x^{\,\overline {\,h\,} } }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   {\left[ \matrix{
  h \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right]} & {\left[ \matrix{
  h \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right]} &  \cdots  & {\left[ \matrix{
  h \cr 
  h \cr}  \right]}  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {x^{\,0} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,1} }  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {x^{\,h} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = {{\bf S}_{\,{\bf t}\,1}} _{\,h}  \,{\bf x}_{\,h} (x)
$$

and we can easily get the conversion of the coefficients as
$$
p_{\,h} (x) = \overline {{\bf a}_{\,h} } \,{\bf x}_{\,h} (x) = \left( {\overline {{\bf a}_{\,h} } \,{{\bf S}_{\,{\bf t}\,1}} _{\,h}  ^{\, - \,1} } \right)\;{\bf y}_{\,h} (x)
$$

Also we have 
$$
{\bf x}_{\,h} (x + 1) = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   1 & 1 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)} & {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)} &  \cdots  & {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right)\,\;{\bf x}_{\,h} (x) = {\bf B}_{\,h} \;{\bf x}_{\,h} (x)
$$

Another important field is that of polynomial interpolation, since we can construct the vector equation involving a Vandermonde matrix as follows
$$
\eqalign{
  & p_{\,h} (x) = \overline {{\bf a}_{\,h} } \,{\bf x}_{\,h} (x)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {p_{\,h} (x_{\,0} ),p_{\,h} (x_{\,1} ), \cdots ,p_{\,h} (x_{\,h} )} \right)
 = \overline {{\bf a}_{\,h} } \left( {{\bf x}_{\,h} (x_{\,0} ),{\bf x}_{\,h} (x_{\,1} ), \cdots ,{\bf x}_{\,h} (x_{\,h} )} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad  \cdots  \cr} 
$$
and you can well figure out the developments that can be attained.

However, the matching between polynomials and vectors is lost in the fundamental field of 
the product and factorization.
We would need to introduce a vector "product" which provides  their convolution.
It would be interesting to ask herewith whether somebody knows about attempts to reconcile
polynomial product with vectors.